How should I set the seeds for worker processes when using ProcessPoolExecutor in Python?
I'm trying to write Python code for a simulation in which each worker process generates a random sample of a user-specified size from a user-specified distribution and then performs some calculations with it. I have done similar simulations in R many times and know that I need to set the seeds for the worker processes properly so that the workers get independent streams of random numbers. I am unsure how to do this in Python. A MWE is below; how should I modify it so that the seeds are properly set? Whenever I run my code, the same samples are repeatedly generated, as the example output shows.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from multiprocessing import get_context

def sample(rv_class, rv_params, rng):
    return rv_class.rvs(**rv_params, random_state=rng)

def simulate(num_samples, max_workers, rv_class, rv_params):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    child_rngs = rng.spawn(max_workers)
    samples = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers, mp_context=get_context("fork")) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(sample, rv_class, rv_params, child_rngs[i % max_workers]) for i in range(num_samples)]
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            samples.append(future.result())
    return samples

if __name__ == "__main__":
    samples = simulate(num_samples=8, max_workers=4, rv_class=st.t, rv_params={"df": 1, "size": 2})
    print(samples)

An example of samples:
[
    array([-0.61049653, -0.24951185]),
    array([-0.93266262, -0.53868302]),
    array([-1.26904811, -1.97301975]),
    array([-0.40024455, -6.65604236]),
    array([-1.26904811, -1.97301975]),
    array([-0.61049653, -0.24951185]),
    array([-0.93266262, -0.53868302]),
    array([-0.40024455, -6.65604236])
]

The YAML file for my conda environment is below. My OS is macOS Sonoma 14.5.
name: env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - numpy=1.26
  - scipy=1.13


Unable to reproduce. Apple M2, MacOS 14.6.1, Python 3.12.5, numpy 2.1.0, scipy 1.14.0 gives different values for each execution of the code shown
